# How to spy a function in Jest that would run on set?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have an object like this:

```js
const obj = {

}
```

And I want to transform it and add a method, and that method will run if a prop exist in that object.

```js
function transform(obj){
   obj.test = () => {
   //Do something
   }

   if(obj.target){
     obj.test()
   }
}

transform(obj)
```

How can I test if this function has run or not? If using `jest.spyOn`, I can only spy on it **after** this method has been added to the obj, which by then the method has already run.

**EDIT**
This is the actual code and the test I am struggling with:
https://github.com/winston0410/camouflage/blob/1811aa85e6f3f966636c3d28f26b91941456a03a/tests/hydration.test.js#L33-L45

Comment: Provide your current test logic.

Comment: Please, provide the exact code, including how modules are related, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . This is very specific to how it was really written. If it was written without testability in mind, you can only test "Do something".

Comment: @hoangdv Thank you for your comment. I have now included the repo for your reference.